# Many-to-Many of members of the same domain class

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

In Grails, I like to have a many-to-many relation among entries **of the same domain class** Person. Relations will link to **different** persons the "leftPerson" and the "rightPerson" since the "Parent-child" and "Employer-Employee" relations will discriminate the position of each link.

That I would like to have is something like the following model:

```
class Person {
  String name

  static hasMany = [relations:Relation]
}

class Relation{
  String type
  Person leftPerson
  Person rightPerson

  static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

Any entry in Relations will be visible from both Persons.

I like to avoid having in Person two entries in'hasMany'and mappedBy if possible.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on many-to-many example of [GORM many-to-many chapter](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1.3%20Many-to-many).

```
class Person { 
    String name
    static hasMany = [relations:Relation]
}
```

```
class Relation {
    String type 
    static hasMany = [persons: Person]
    static belongsTo = Person
}
```